# How to fetch xargs command output and exit code

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I need to fetch both the exit code of a command started with xargs and the standard output. Here is my command line:

```
RESULT=`ls -1t . | grep \\.sh\$ | xargs -d '\n' yad --list --no-headers  --button DELETE:2 --button BACKUP:1 --button CANCEL:0 --column=1:TEXT`
RETVALUE=$?
```

The RESULT variable respect the selection of the `yad` list but the RETVALUE doesn't respect the pressed button.
As explained on xargs man page, the exit code is 123 if the command (yad in the example) exit with a value other than 0.

Comment: Please include a [mre] and describe the expected behavior more clearly.

Comment: @oguzismail I changed a little the description of obtained result for the sample code. Please help me describing better my issue

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down? For example, if you get rid of the backticks do you get the expected result from xargs/yad? Is it only when capturing the output or do they do the wrong thing regardless?

Comment: What if you replace `xargs yad ...` with `xargs false` or `xargs sh -c 'echo result; exit 5'`?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `yad` will be executed **once**? What do you expect in `RETVALUE` if one invocation returns 1 and the other returns 2?

Comment: `yad` is executed once. If I remove backticks I receive the same exit code (backticks don't change exit code of the last command). I'm thinking if exists a complete different solution in wich I'm able to redirect the exit code of a command to an environment variable...

Comment: Another solution is to use `find . -exec ...` instead of `ls -1 | xargs` but even `find` doesn't propagate the exit code of the command

Comment: If you *know* `yad` will execute only once, you shoudn't be using `xargs` in the first place. (Nor should you be parsing the output of `ls`.  If there is exactly one file that would match `.sh`, you can just use `yad ... *.sh`.)

Comment: If there is any chance at all that there is no matching file, or multiple files, you should use a regular `for` loop to run `yad` and handle its exit status for each file individually.

Comment: @chepner I need to run `yad` once becouse I need to show the list of every file catched by the grep, than the user need to select one item from the list and press a button, I need to know the chosen item and the pressed button

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution modifying `IFS`.

```
LIST=`ls -1t . | grep \\.sh\$`
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS='
'
RESULT=`yad --list --no-headers  --button DELETE:2 --button BACKUP:1 --button CANCEL:0 --column=1:TEXT $LIST`
RETVALUE=$?
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

This way I avoid using `xargs` (so I'm able to fetch the correct exit code of yad) and I have the ability to correctly handle element with white space.